# Implementing didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken in a Swift extension does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to slowly migrate from Obj-C to Swift. My first step is to migrate small, simple methods to Swift extensions so I decided to try and migrate `didRegisterForRemoteNotifications` but that didn't work because it thinks the method is implemented somewhere else in my Objective-C code. It is not.

I'm using Xcode 7.3 (7D175)

Here's some reproduction steps:

- Create a new Obj-C project.
- Create a new empty Swift file called `AppDelegate-Extension.swift`. This also creates a Bridging header file.
- Add `#import AppDelegate.h` to the Briding header file.
- Go to the empty Swift file and type:

  ```
  extension AppDelegate {

      public func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

      }
  }
  ```

This causes to compiler to complain:

> method 'application(_:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:)' with Objective-C selector 'application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:' conflicts with previous declaration with the same Objective-C selector
>       public func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
>                   ^
>   __ObjC.AppDelegate:38:17: note: 'application' previously declared here
>       public func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData)

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** 
Some suggestions that I've tried:

> Add `override` to the method declaration so it reads `override public ...`

This returns the following error (in addition to the original error)

> error: method does not override any method from its superclass
>       override public func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData)

Comment: what do you mean swift header file? You should create Bridge class and import your `AppDelegate.h` there

Comment: Sorry, that's exactly what I meant. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: try `override func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {`

Comment: `error: method does not override any method from its superclass
    override public func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData)`

Comment: `conflicts with previous declaration with the same Objective-C selector` and `ObjC.AppDelegate:38:17: note: 'application' previously declared here` seem to suggest you´ve already implemented the method in your AppDelegate.m. Can you make sure that this is not the case?

Comment: As answered by Paulw11, it's not that (I didn't have the method implemented). It's the actual _declaration_ that's the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you can't use an extension in this way in a mixed Swift & Objective-C environment.

In Swift, you can use an extension to provide implementations for functions that have been declared in a protocol that is adopted by a class.  This is the core of 'protocol-oriented-programming'

In Objective-C, a category is used to add additional functions to an existing class.  When you create your Swift extension, Xcode creates a *targetname-Swift.h* file in the derived-data folder. Now, you can't see this file because your compile is failing, but if you change your extension slightly so that the compilation works

```
extension AppDelegate {
    public func application(app application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {    
    }
}
```

and then you look at this file you will find something like:

```
@interface AppDelegate (SWIFT_EXTENSION(XTNTest))
    - (void)applicationWithApp:(UIApplication * _Nonnull)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData * _Nonnull)deviceToken;
@end
```

Note how your extension method has been added as a category onto `AppDelegate`. Now, imagine what this file would look like if you had the correct form of your function (no `app` in the signature)

```
@interface AppDelegate (SWIFT_EXTENSION(XTNTest))
    - (void)application:(UIApplication * _Nonnull)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData * _Nonnull)deviceToken;
@end
```

This is a re-declaration of a method that is already declared in the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol.

The upshot of all this is that you either need to adopt Swift on a class-by-class basis or you need to use subclassing if you want to use a function-by-function basis since there is a difference between an Objective-C category and a Swift extension.

Comment: Yep. My Test-Swift.h autogenerated file looks very similar to what you mentioned... Thanks!